# How to Mirror MariaDB schema into Mysql?

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, mirroring

We are using MariaDB for our main service and Mysql on another for our ATM machines, I trying to fetch all the data and to have all the transactions available.

I don't know if this is possible because Mysql and MariaDB are not the same...

We also would consider changing the main server to Mysql as an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it rather worrying that you are responsible for developing software for banking transactions but don't know how to find the answers for yourself and are asking the question in the wrong way. But that's more a comment than an answer.

The relative age of the installation is at least as important as the fact that one instance is Mariadb and one is MySQL.

If they are roughly the same age, the [asynchonronous replication](http://www.clusterdb.com/mysql-cluster/setting-up-mysql-asynchronous-replication-for-high-availability) should work. Using Galera replication really would not be appropriate in this context. However you need to ensure this doesn't conflict with any replication already in place - and if we are talking about significant volumes of financial transactions you should already have that in place to ensure availability of the service.

Alternatively you can simply run

```
mysqldump -h hostA srcdb | mysql -h hostB destdb
```

....assuming you are not using particularly esoteric functionality (most of which could be handled with a sed filter). But this copies the whole database each time.

However both approaches have a number of limitations and significant implications for your overall security. Security is usually quite high on the list of priorities for a bank - and the right solution depends on what architectures and controls are in place - which we know nothing about.

I suspect that the most appropriate strategy would be to send the updates across an asynchronous message queue with end to end acknowledgements (i.e. each transaction flagged as replicated in the source then it has been ingested at the destination database. This requires custom code.

Comment: We are a cryptocurrency "bank" if you can say so (we only have 15 atms) ... Sorry for asking the question in the wrong way... I'm not a system admin... my knowledge in databases and systems is at moust junior, also we only have 2 developers, 1 for front and I in back